# NextJs 13 return ELIFECYCLE Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: next.js, webassembly, next.js13, swc

I tried to run NextJS 13, but got this error:

```
cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/57c29e4f-7f76-4028-97e0-f004c069b964
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
- ready started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49335/9372f339-5331-4ff6-b8bd-a7bf179a9099
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
- info Loaded env from .env
- info the --inspect option was detected, the Next.js server for app should be inspected at port 49344.
- info the --inspect option was detected, the Next.js server for pages should be inspected at port 49345.
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49344/de152b09-7efd-429c-8350-1101b1089fe8
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49345/5d218e1c-aa06-4e49-a6ff-c1f40471eaff
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
- info Using wasm build of next-swc
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

and couldn't find any clue from the internet